# How to set C++11 as my default compiler?

Tags: compiling, g++

I am using Ubuntu.

When programming in C++, the `nullptr` keyword is not recognized by the compiler.

It says *it's not declared at this scope*.

It doesn't work, even though I set the flag `-std=c++11`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could state what compiler you are using.

Comment: I am using the compiler g++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++11 isn't a compiler, but an ISO standard implemented by a number of popular compilers. The default C++ compiler on Ubuntu is `g++` from the GNU Compiler Collection. As you mentioned in your question, the `-std=c++11` flag enables C++11 features in `g++` as well as Clang, another C++ compiler available on Ubuntu.

The error message you see is shown when C++11 support is either not enabled or not supported by your compiler. GCC 4.6 was the first version to support `nullptr`, so if you are using an earlier version, you will not be able to use `nullptr`. Use `g++ --version` to obtain the version installed.

Assuming you are using at least GCC 4.6, you will need to determine why your build system is not passing the correct flags to the compiler. In CMake, for example, you will need to use:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

Comment: Thanks.  How to fix it then? I am using Ubuntu 14

Comment: How are you compiling the program?

Comment: g++ -o -std=c++11 run program.cpp

Comment: The order of arguments is wrong. It should be `g++ program.cpp -o run -std=c++11`

Comment: Yes, it's the order of command.